# c# (beginner) how to make a short version of this "if" code?

Tags: c#

I just learned how to use if and tried to do a simple calculator. but the code is way too long and i want to add more options to it, can i make it any shorter using any other method?

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you wish to calculate? ");
        string HowMany = Console.ReadLine();
        if (HowMany == "2") {
            Console.Write("Enter #1: ");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #2: ");
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int sum = x + y; int sub = x - y; int mult = x * y; int div = x / y;
            Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = " + sum + " Sub = " + sub + " Mult = " + mult + " Div = " + div); }
        else if (HowMany == "3") {
            Console.Write("Enter #1: ");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #2: ");
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #3: ");
            int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int sum = x + y + z; int sub = x - y - z; int mult = x * y * z; int div = x / y / z;
            Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = " + sum + " Sub = " + sub + " Mult = " + mult + " Div = " + div); }
        else if (HowMany == "4")
        {
            Console.Write("Enter #1: ");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #2: ");
            int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #3: ");
            int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter #4: ");
            int w = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int sum = x + y + z + w; int sub = x - y - z - w; int mult = x * y * z * w; int div = x / y / z / w;
            Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = " + sum + " Sub = " + sub + " Mult = " + mult + " Div = " + div);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Time to learn the `for` loop.

Comment: You can stuff all the of the junk inside the `if` statements into a method. So you only have to write all that junk once and within each `if` statement just pass different arguments to the method

Comment: do a for loop.  ask them to enter 1 number at a time.  when they hit enter, with no number entered, stop and show the result.  Only 1 `if` statement needed.

Comment: You can write this code without ifs

Comment: Normally you're going to want to do one calculation on two numbers at a time anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This does just the sum. I'll leave handling the other calculations to you.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1;i<=HowMany;i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter #{0}: ", i);
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += input;
}
Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = {0}", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program {
 static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine("How many numbers do you wish to calculate? ");
  string HowMany = Console.ReadLine();

  int[] nums = new int[int.Parse(HowMany)];
  int sum = 0, sub = 0, mult = 1, div = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(HowMany); i++) {
   Console.Write("Enter #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
   nums[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   sum += nums[i];
   sub -= nums[i];
   mult *= nums[i];
   div /= nums[i];
  }

  Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = " + sum + " Sub = " + sub + " Mult = " + mult + " Div = " + div);

  Console.ReadKey();
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but it looks like if the user enters 2 numbers: `6` and `3`, the `div` is going to be wrong since the first division will be `1 / 6`

Comment: Yeah, you're right )

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a loop, and keep a rolling total of the values. Also, I changed `div` to be a `double`, because integer division is really boring - it's nice to see the decimal value:

I also made it so the user can only enter an integer greater than zero for the quantity of numbers they want to calculate.

And finally, they can only enter a non-zero integer for the number, because a zero input means we have to do some check for that during division, the multiplication value will always be zero, and it does nothing to the addition and subtraction totals.

```
Console.Write("How many numbers do you wish to calculate? ");
int count;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count) || count < 1)
{
    Console.Write("Error: enter a positive, whole number: ");
}

int input, sum = 0, sub = 0, mult = 0;
double div = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Enter #{i}: ");

    // Don't allow user to enter 0. It does nothing to the addition or subtraction
    // values, will make the multiplication value zero, and cannot be use for division
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || input == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Error: enter a non-zero whole number: ");
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        // On the first input, we just store the number
        sum = sub = mult = input;
        div = input;
    }
    else
    {
        sum += input;
        sub -= input;
        mult *= input;
        div /= input;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The Result : Sum = " + sum + " Sub = " + 
    sub + " Mult = " + mult + " Div = " + div);

Console.ReadKey();
```